# Using Print to write the formatted text to a file

Tags: excel, vba

I created the output strings from worksheet in VBA macro and tried to print them for each line of text file using Print, the expected output like this:

```
class A
{
public:
       UINT8                                            tbcDatabaseValidSpecialFunc;
       TbcDatabaseCycleDefTable                         tbcDatabaseCycleDefTable[MAX_CONFIG_TBC_DATABASE_CYCLE_DEF];
       UINT8                                            MiscEthernetSpeed;
};
```

Question:
How can I print the aligned column inside of class A using Print? Like this:

```
output_string = var_type + var
Print #textfile, output_string
```

The length of var_type(first column) is variant, and how can I align the var(2nd column)?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a maximum length for `var_type`? if yes, then filling it using e.g. `Space()` could lead to a fixed column width (in means of a fix number of characters per column):

```
Const cColumnChars as Integer = 20
output_string = var_type & Space(cColumnChars - Len(var_type)) & var
```

Note: If `var_type` is numeric, then `Format()` might help bringing it into shape.

Comment: no maximum length for var_type, but I can count the maximum length through the whole worksheet first and then set to a fixed col width using ur method. Thx!